# Change page like jQuery mobile with animation?

Tags: javascript, html

It is posible to change the URL in the location bar and load the new page with a animation like in jQuery mobile framework.

How?

Comment: You can have more and better answers if you first try something and show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible: any thing that can be done with jQuery mobile (or any other javascript library/framework) can also be done using vanilla Javascript. Since you aren't providing any source code I suppose you are expecting a hint on how to do it (stack overflow users are usually more motivated to help if you provide the code you have already tried).

Assuming that you are going to use at least jQuery (or other js framework):

- Load the new page using `jQuery.get()` (you have to retrieve it as 'html').
- Save the response text inside a jQuery object: `var myPage = jQuery(MyCallResponseText)`.
- Use jQuery's function `find` in order to get a specific div from `myPage` which is the wrapper of the content you want to display (please note that neither the header not the body tags are going to be found inside `myPage`).
- Create a new div `myContainer` with a width and height of 100%, position fixed, z-index 10, and display none.
- Append to `myContainer` with the whole `myPage` object (or its content), add the div to the body of current page and finally animate.

Note about the scripts: any script contained in `myPage` will be evaluated when adding it to the DOM, but non of the script in the head will be.

For the animation, you can use jQuery's `Animate` function. For example: Set opacity of `myContainer` to 0 and display to block, and then animate opacity from 0 to 1, this way you'll get a fadeIn animation. Of course, the same animation may also be done calling `myContainer.fadeIn()` instead.